# Objeto para JSONValue via DataSnap

Tags: json, delphi, datasnap

Ola, 
Tenho o seguinte objeto:

```
  TResult = Class
  private
    FStatus  : TStatus;
    FMensagem: string;
    FEntidade: string;
    FLista   : TFDJSONDataSets; //tentei esse
    FLista2  : TFDMemTable;     //segunda tentativa - um ou outro...
  public
    constructor Create;
    Destructor Destroy; override;

    property Status  : TStatus         read FStatus write FStatus;
    property Mensagem: string          read FMensagem write FMensagem;
    property Entidade: string          read FEntidade write FEntidade;
    property Lista   : TFDJSONDataSets read FLista write FLista;
    property Lista2  : TFDMemTable     read FLista2 write FLista2;
  End;
```

em um server datasnap, preciso transportá-lo para o cliente, entao para isso estou convertendo esse objeto com:

```
function ResultToJSON(AResult: TResult): TJSONValue;
var
  m: TJSONMarshal;
begin
  if Assigned(AResult) then
  begin
    m := TJSONMarshal.Create(TJSONConverter.Create);
    try
      exit(m.Marshal(AResult))
    finally
      m.Free;
    end;
  end
  else
    exit(TJSONNull.Create);
end;
```

As propertys Lista ou Lista2 é para transportar o resultado de uma consulta (n registros), porém na "desconversão" da erro, ja tentei com JSONArray tb...

Se alguem puder me dizer como transportar o resultado de uma consulta dentro de um objeto, para ser transportado via datasnap, agradeço muito.

adendo: popular lista e lista2:

```
function GetList(ATexto: string): TResult;
var _cds: TFDMemTable;
begin

  Result := TResult.Create;
  with result do
  begin
    try
      _cds := _objDAO.GetList(ATexto);

      if _cds <> nil then
      begin
        Status   := tsOK;
     //   Lista    := TFDJSONDataSets.Create;          --testes
     //   TFDJSONDataSetsWriter.ListAdd(Lista, _cds);  --testes
     //   Lista2   := _cds;                            --testes
      end
      else
        Status   := tsVazio;
    except
      on e:exception do
      begin
        Status   := tsErro;
        Mensagem := LimpaErro(e.Message);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Olá. Então, em JSON o correto é transportar array de strings ou objetos. No seu caso eu definiria uma segunda classe com os campos que você quer transportar e no seu objeto TResult.Lista eu definiria um array desta segunda classe. É assim que faço em uma API antiga em delphi que tenho que transporta todos os tipos de dados, listas e estruturas que preciso. Não tem segredo se trabalhar assim.

Comment: O que não dá pra fazer é transportar algumas classes do delphi serializando e de-serializando novamente. Ou seja, cria uma classe sua, de-serializa o objeto e então você inicializa uma instância do TFDJSONDataSets ou TFDMemTable e preenche-os com os dados já recebidos. Agora transportá-los diretamente não vai dar.

Comment: Obrigado pelo seu comentário... realmente eu fiz assim, consegui, transformei FLista numa string e transporto ela como um arrayjson, a um tempo atrás eu tive problema com essa conversao, nem lembrava mais dessa função que encontrei e alterei para resolver o problema de campos memo e blob...